# Can we have 2 return statements in component in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have one component named ShowProduct
in that I am having images of products
From CardMedia I am calling handleChalCharkha function that is defined in ShowProduct component

```
{value.products.map((item) => (
      <CardActionArea
        style={{
          width: "140px",
          height: "140px",
          innerWidth: "100px",
          padding: "10px",
          margin: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="240"
          image={item.image}
          alt={item.id}
          title={item.name}
          sx={{ padding: "1em 1em 0 1em", height: "140px", width: "100px" }}
          onClick={(event) => handleChalCharkha(event, value.name)}
        />
           { showChalCharkha && 
         <ShowChalCharkha value={selectedMessage}></ShowChalCharkha>}
  
      </CardActionArea>
    ))}
        />
```

Card Media is written under return statement-->
so on clicking of images I have to render another component that is handleChalCharkha
that code is written below

```
const handleChalCharkha = (event, message) => {
console.log("handleChalCharkha function=>", event.target);
console.log("message", message);

// return <ShowChalCharkha value={message}></ShowChalCharkha>;
return(
  <>
  <div>
  <ShowChalCharkha value={message}></ShowChalCharkha>
  </div>
  </>
)
```

};

Above both code are written inside a ShowProduct component

and below is the ShowChalCharkha component

```
export default function ShowChalCharkha({value}) {
console.log('from show chal charkha component',value);
console.log('chal charkha is called')
}
```

but when I console showChalCharkha component , it is not rendering
Please suggest me what I have to do

Comment: Do you have to show both the CardMedia and the ShowChalCharkha component when clicking an image or either one of them, so when clicking the image CardMedia disappears and ShowChalCharkha appears?

Comment: The code shown doesn't make any sense to me.  If `ShowChalCharkha` is a *component*, it currently doesn't return *anything*, so it's not clear what that component is meant to render in any markup structure.  And `handleChalCharkha` is a *click handler*, in which returning a value is meaningless because the system isn't going to do anything with that returned value.  I suspect the problem has nothing to do with "2 return statements" (which isn't really clear to begin with) and more to do with how to dynamically show/hide elements/components in React (which would be driven by *state*).

Comment: @L_Cleo yes CardMedia image will disappear and ShowChalCharkha component will show, as of now I have not routed to that path , as I have to fetch API then display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have doesn't make sense since you can't return JSX from a click handler and expect it to render. You need to modify some state that says which product was clicked, and then use that state to conditionally render what you want.

You can think of a React component as a pure function where the state goes in and JSX comes out. You can't have "multiple return statements". If you need to change what is output, you need to add conditionals inside the JSX, which would usually be asserting the condition on some state. Once you have that, therefore, it's a case of changing that state to meet the condition on some user action (like in the click handler).

We introduce `selectedProductId` state that holds the `id` of the clicked product. This defaults to `null` which means nothing is selected and therefore, `ShowChalCharkha` won't render anywhere until something is clicked (which will set `selectedProductId` to the `id` of the clicked item) since we now conditionally render it based on this piece of state.

Now we are storing the `id` of the last clicked item, we can compare in the JSX if the item currently being iterated over matches this selection, and only show the `ShowChalCharkha` component for the product which was clicked, and not the others.

```
const ShowProduct = () => {
  const [selectedProductId, setSelectedProductId] = useState(null)

  const handleChalCharkha = (event, id) => {
    setSelectedProductId(id)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {value.products.map((item) => (
        <>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="240"
            image={item.image}
            alt={item.id}
            title={item.name}
            sx={{ padding: "1em 1em 0 1em", height: "140px", width: "100px" }}
            onClick={(event) => handleChalCharkha(event, item.id)}
          />
          {selectedProductId === item.id && (
            <ShowChalCharkha value={item}></ShowChalCharkha>
          )}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply , I tried your solution but I have to render ShowChalCharkha whenever I click Image , so I cant write below CardMedia , I have to return frm handleChalCharkha component

Comment: This code does exactly that, did you definitely run it?. It will only render when an image is clicked and not before. The `ShowChalCharkha` is rendered CONDITIONALLY because of the `selectedMessage !== null && ` which only evaluates to true once `setSelectedMessage` is called, which is only called when the user clicks an image. Until an image is clicked, it will not render with the above code.

Comment: yes you are right , it renders when I click on Image, but it rendered 6 times in console , as I have 6 images on UI , so I want to render that component each click, 
after that I have to call ShowChalCharkha API to display complete detail of product (image=product)and route it to different path , sorry I am very less experienced as I am very new to React js, recently started to learn

Comment: No worries. Im a bit lost -- ignoring the console.logs, is the user behaviour correct above or no? Keep in mind, react re-renders are not something to reduce or prevent as they are usually benign.

Comment: Ah I see you updated your post. I understand now. I will edit answer give me some mins.

Comment: Ok cool, ive reworked it now so it only shows for the image that was selected and not the other ones. The way to do this is we store the `id` of the selected item only and then in the `map`, we check if the card being iterated on at that time matches the one that was selected by comparing their `id`s. This way only the single image that was selected will get its `ShowChalCharkha` rendered, and not the other ones.

Comment: oh my god, you are super awesome , it worked as expected , tfrom morning I was trying.. thank you very much for your big help :)

Comment: No worries! The trick is that if you need to render something in response to some user interaction, you need to store some state that represents that interaction (in this case, the id of the product clicked), then figure out the logic to render what you need based on that state (in this case, only render `ShowChalCharkha` for the product that matches the stored id) .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `onClick` does not support rendering of components. What you can do is use the `react-hooks` library to help you out with your challenge.
What you want to do is conditionally show ShowChalCharkha when the state `showChalCharkha` state of your `ShowProduct` component updates to true and hide it when it updates to false.

To do this, within your `ShowProduct` component you'll have something like this:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function ShowProduct() {

    const [showChalCharkha, setShowChalCharkha] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    //... your other business logic

    const handleChalCharkha = (event, message) => {
        //logs

        //update your component's state
        setMessage(message);
        setShowChalCharkha(true);
    }

    return (
        //...
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="240"
          image={item.image}
          alt={item.id}
          title={item.name}
          sx={{ padding: "1em 1em 0 1em", height: "140px", width: "100px" }}
          onClick={(event) => handleChalCharkha(event, value.name)}
        />
        //show your Charkha component only when the state showChalCharkha is true
        { showChalCharkha &&
            <div>
                <ShowChalCharkha value={message}></ShowChalCharkha>
            </div>
        }
        //...
    )

}
```

This way the ShowChalCharkha will only show when your state of ShowProduct equals to true. (Side note: when updating your states the render function gets called again)

Comment: thank you for reply , I tried your solution but I have to render ShowChalCharkha whenever I click Image , so I cant write below CardMedia , I have to return frm handleChalCharkha component 
so is there any way to call component on each click or return component from handleChalCharkha function